# cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/discord: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused

Tags: linux

I want to install discord via snap (Linux package format), but i get the following error:

```
cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/discord: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
```

Don't know why ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe you don't have the snad service running

To start it onetimes do:

```
sudo systemctl start snapd
```

To enable that it always start with your system do:

```
sudo systemctl enable snapd
```

Answer (score 6):

Unmask it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service
```

Enable it:

```
sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
```

Start it:

```
sudo systemctl start snapd.service
```

Comment: * TECHNOLOGIC! *

Comment: it'd be great to get a little context behind each of these commands.

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same issue for some time now.
I solved the issue by uninstalling snap and then reinstalling it:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
$ sudo apt install snapd
```

Comment: This command makes you loses something - like firefox install I did to use in terminal with xdg-open (or others that I don't know yet) - and didn't solve my problem (wsl2). There is a specific thing about snap that makes the question opened because it still happens...

Answer (score 2):

This solution finally worked for me with a slight addition

sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
sudo apt install snapd

On purging /var/snap/firefox would not purge , it was marked as a read only

I renamed the whole snap firefox folder and repeated the purge until I had a clean purge

Finally the snapd install went though as a clean install
I checked with
journalctl -xeu snapd.service

Comment: This worked for me too, but small warning is that you will lose all snap app, so better back it up

Answer (score 1):

This issue came to me because i changed permission to 777
I searched every where and I find only this solution is best
sudo apt-get purge snapd
sudo apt-get install snapd

Answer (score 1):

This issue came when i was trying to install spotify on my kali machine using snap "snapd"
so this issue can be solved with the following commands on the terminal
Firstly install snap `**$ sudo apt install snapd**`
or remove it by `**$ sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd**`  then install it again
Then enter the following commands

```
$ sudo systemctl enable snapd`
$ sudo systemctl start snapd 
$ sudo snap install spotify
```

you should be able to download spotify on your kali/ubuntu Machine